# Read pcap files online with scapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, pcap, libpcap, scapy

I would like to use Scapy to analyze an ongoing packet capture online - that is, I need to be able to get the rest of the packets that have been written so far and return, not block until the whole capture has been read. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: So essentially, you want to be able to `tail -f` but for PCAPs? This sounds interesting...